# How to get rid of black bars when playing SplitScreen Mode?

Tags: ps3, resident-evil-6, resident-evil-5

Even on a standard 4:3 SD TV, the black bars on the sides appears, eating a little of screen space.

Is there anyway for me to make the split screen top and bottom fill the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is the way they made it which is pretty lame especially on HDtv, but hey you can now run and shoot.